# Curve_fit with dataframes TypeError:Improper Input

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, typeerror, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to perform a linear fit of the values from two DataFrames. The following code is part of my script, where i am working mainly with DataFrames.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

X = np.array([[76.17E-3,52.62E-3,42.95E-3,29.78E-3,27.50E-3,21.78E-3,14.00E-3,7.45E-3]])

Y = np.array([[4.573085e+06,3.906632e+06,3.589304e+06,3.408189e+06,3.149472e+06,3.010599e+06,2.678995e+06,2.599270e+06]])

X = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
Y = pd.DataFrame(data=Y)

print(type(X))
print(X.shape)
print(type(Y))
print(Y.shape)

def Parameters(X, A, B):
    return A + B*X

def fit_Parameters(X):
    As = []
    Bs = []
    Fit_AB = []
    popt = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(Parameters, X, Y, p0=None, maxfev=5000, method='lm')
    A, B = popt
    fitted_parameters = Parameters(X, A, B)
    As.append(A)
    Bs.append(B)
    Fit_AB.append(fitted_parameters)
    print(fitted_parameters)
    return As, Bs, Fit_AB

As, Bs, Fit_AB = fit_Parameters(X)

plt.plot(X, Y, marker='*', color='b', markersize=13)
plt.plot(X, Fit_AB, linestyle='dashed', color='k')
plt.show()
```

I obtain the next output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(1, 8)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(1, 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//Try_pandas to fit.py", line 37, in <module>   
    As, Bs, Fit_AB = fit_Parameters(X)
  File "//Try_pandas to fit.py", line 28, in fit_Parameters
    Parameters, X, Y, p0=None, maxfev=5000, method='lm')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 763, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 392, in leastsq
    raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
TypeError: Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1
```

I have tried also to do it with arrays instead of DataFrames, but still the same output error.
Does anyone have the idea why this error occurs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey about this certain error your X and y should be one dimension

[image]

here how to fix it:
if you don't have control on the data you can use squeeze()

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdata = np.array([[76.17E-3,52.62E-3,42.95E-3,29.78E-3,27.50E-3,21.78E-3,14.00E-3,7.45E-3]])

ydata = np.array([[4.573085e+06,3.906632e+06,3.589304e+06,3.408189e+06,3.149472e+06,3.010599e+06,2.678995e+06,2.599270e+06]])

X = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
Y = pd.DataFrame(data=Y)

print(type(X))
print(X.shape)
print(type(Y))
print(Y.shape)

def Parameters(X, A, B ):
   return A + B*X

xdata =xdata.squeeze()
ydata = ydata.squeeze()

print("x:" , xdata)
print("y:" ,ydata)
popt = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(Parameters, xdata, ydata, p0=None, maxfev=5000, method='lm')
popt
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your error suggests, the code fails at this point:

```
popt = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(Parameters, X, Y, p0=None, maxfev=5000, method='lm')
```

You can fix this by replacing this line above with these 3:

```
XX=[each for lst in X.values for each in lst]
YY=[each for lst in Y.values for each in lst]
popt = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(Parameters, XX, YY, p0=None, maxfev=5000, method='lm')
```

The script will still have a bug, at a later point, but that is a separate issue I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with just 1-dimensional numpy arrays, no need for pandas:

```
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

X = np.array([76.17E-3,52.62E-3,42.95E-3,29.78E-3,27.50E-3,21.78E-3,14.00E-3,7.45E-3])
Y = np.array([4.573085e+06,3.906632e+06,3.589304e+06,3.408189e+06,3.149472e+06,3.010599e+06,2.678995e+06,2.599270e+06])

def func(X, A, B):
    return A + B*X

popt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, X, Y, p0=None, maxfev=5000, method='lm')

popt
array([ 2371977.38020794, 29163368.07469793])
```